# Persisting display data on Form Submission failure in Asp Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Given I have the simple scenario below, how does one persist the display data, i.e. InfoAboutInput, when a form post validation fails on the server side? 
Would I have to rely on a session based cache to repopulate my model on the server side if it the model validation fails? Or is there some other trick that can be employed to do that?

Simple ViewModel:

```
public class FormViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    public string InfoAboutInput { get; set; } // customised display info per user    
    public string UserInput { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
         // perform some specialised validation on UserInput
    }
}
```

Simple Consuming View:

```
@model FormViewModel
<div>
    <form>
        <h3>@Model.InfoAboutInput</h3>
        <input asp-for="UserInput"/>
        <button>Submit</button>
    <form>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to reload the model and return it from the controller action

Answer (score 0):

The controller action which catches the post will have access to any form fields and their values.  In this action, simply create a new model, populate it from the db or whatever, and populate any posted back values using the form values.  Then return the model as the result of the controller action.